# Mocha testing with promises: Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, parse-server

I'm encountering this very popular issue, there were many solutions out there but none of them worked for me.

I get this error: Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Here is my code:

```
describe('POST before and afterSave("ticket")', () => {
    it('should save ticket credentials correctly', () => {
        // console.log(ticket);
        ticket.set("status", "pending");
        return ticket.save(null, { useMasterKey: true 
}).then(function(object) {
            console.log("hi2");
            expect(object).toExist();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("hi3");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: How long does `ticket.save()` typically take to finish?

Comment: should be a couple of seconds... but if that's the case, and it takes longer than 2 secs to save, what's the resolution?

Comment: Reading [the fine manual](https://mochajs.org/#timeouts) ;D

Comment: still getting errors about timeouts